# Handling corrupt JSON structure with Athena AWS ( HIVE_BAD_DATA)

Tags: json, hive, amazon-athena

I need to access a JSON structure from the table "data_test":

```
id (string)
att (struct<field1:string;field2:string;field3:int>)
```

```
 SELECT
    id,
    att.field1,
    att.field2,
    att.field3
 FROM database.data_test as rawdata
```

I receive the following error:

> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value for field 1: For input
>   string: "2147483648"

So, as I understand do I have a numeric-value 2147483648 in string-field, that causes the corrupt data.

Then I tried to CAST the string-fields as varchar, but the result was the same.

```
 SELECT
    id,
    CAST(att.field1 as VARCHAR) as field1,
    CAST(att.field2 as VARCHAR) as field2,
    att.field3
 FROM database.data_test as rawdata
```

> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value for field 1: For input
>   string: "2147483648"

When I just select the id, than everything works fine.

```
 SELECT
    id
 FROM database.data_test as rawdata
```

Unfortunately, I do not even know the IDs of the corrupt data, otherwise I would just skip them with the WHERE-clause. I just have access over Athena to the data, so it is hard for me to get more information.
I asked the AWS-admin to add the ignore.malformed -option, so that the JSON-file do not allow corrupt data. He told me, that he can not do it, because than to much data will be skipped.

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
```

The admin gave me the DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ${dbName}.${tableName}(
  `id` string, 
  `att` struct<field1:string,field2:string,field3:int>
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('paths'='att') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://${outPutS3BucketLocation}'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='create_benchmark_athena_table', 
  'averageRecordSize'='87361', 
  'classification'='json', 
  'compressionType'='gzip', 
  'objectCount'='1', 
  'recordCount'='100', 
  'sizeKey'='315084', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

I have three questions:

- Is there a way to SELECT even corrupt data e.g. all fields as a string?
- Can I just skip the corrupt data in SELECT statement?
- How can I get more information e.g. the id-field of the corrupt data to skip it in where-clause?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post sample records an DDL of the table?

Comment: I added the DDL in the post.